# Patch value is not setting the value to the mat-select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a mat-select dropdown in a form along with many other controls. I did patch value after getting from DB. Everything is getting mapped except for mat-select.

UI Code

```
<mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
<mat-select formControlName="organization"  >
   <mat-option [value]="0">None</mat-option>
   <mat-option [value]="1">Bank Operations (Mike Conticello)</mat-option>
   <mat-option [value]="2">Brokerage product Services (Kent Clark)</mat-option>
   <mat-option [value]="3">Custody & Asset Services ( Staci Sullivan)</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

TS code

```js
this.nominationSvc.GetNominationById(this.id)
  .then(
    result => {
        if (result != null) {
          console.log(result.organization);
          this.nominationForm.patchValue(result);
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you share the value of `result`?

Comment: adaptable: false
challenger: false
collaborative: true
createDateUTC: "2022-06-15T00:07:00"
createdBy: "veena.panakanapalli"
demonstratedNote: "fdgfdghfd"
department: "test test"
developsOthers: false
id: 26
inspiresPurpose: false
isEditable: true
leader: "testsetes"
organization: "1"
otherNote: "dfrgfdgd"
quarter: 2
responsible: false
role: "testtest"
serviceCentric: true
solutionDriven: false
updateDateUTC: "2022-06-15T00:07:00"
updatedBy: "veena.panakanapalli"
userEmail: "test@gmail.com"
userName: "leadership nomination"
[[Prototype]]: Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `organization` value in `result` was a string,

Change the mat-option value to string

```
 <mat-select formControlName="organization"  >
    <mat-option [value]="'0'">None</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="'1'">Bank Operations (Mike Conticello)</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="'2'">Brokerage product Services (Kent Clark)</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="'3'">Custody & Asset Services ( Staci Sullivan)</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```